# Procedure takes long time under concurrent requests

Tags: java, mysql

Our web-application is under development mode and I have seen a pattern replicate. i.e. MySQl procedures runtime increases linearly with number of requests.

Our db is pretty small (~500mb). On opening a page, 3 procedures are called in parallel (only read, no write). On a normal run, I have observed that it takes about `0.5 sec` for a procedure to run. But interesting thing to observe is that, when 3 users open the page: it takes about 3 seconds to process (i.e. 9 procedures are called).

> For 5 users (i.e. 15 procedures) about 11 seconds
>
> For 10 users (i.e.
>   30 procedures) about 20 seconds

And for more users, it even increases to 40+. After which even if I try connecting my database from mysql workbench or so, it doesn't connect till I restart it. Procedures are all read-only.

I am calling it from `Spring JDBC`. My `config.xml`:

```
//DBCP connection pool settings.
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close" p:initialSize="20" p:maxActive="-1" p:minIdle="5"
    p:maxIdle="35" p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
    p:url="jdbc:mysql://10.0.1.100/warehouse?useUnicode=true&amp;"
    p:username="user" p:password="123" p:testOnBorrow="true"
    p:validationQuery="SELECT 1" />
<bean id="jdbcTemplate" class="org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate">
    <property name="dataSource">
        <ref bean="dataSource" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

Question: Has it got to do with configuring MySQL? Or my DBCP connection pool? What else can be the reason for the behavior?

Comment: It may well be down to MySQL. Try serializing access to it, by enforcing a `syncronized` block around db access code, and see if it makes a difference.

Comment: It indeed will (tried it already). But then it again is an bottleneck.

Comment: Maybe you are reusing single connection to DB? This seems that response time multiplies exactly as number of requests grow. So throughput stays the same. DB is supposed to be more parallel.

Comment: Nope. That is why I am using DBCP connection pool to manage my connections with no upper limit.

Comment: @Jatin `synchronized` is for *diagnostics*, not for *fixing*. Aren't you trying to pinpoint the source of your problem?

Comment: This may sound naive but, isn't it normal that if for 5 users you need about 10 seconds to complete the job, when you scale up to 10 users you need about 20 seconds instead? I mean, it would be stranger if you needed 40 seconds for 10 users, but a linear increase does not sound so strange to me.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik I am sorry I didn't get you. If you meant to validate the source as 'db'? I have tried it and runs as expected. But when I remove synchronization, the above behavior is observed.

Comment: This, and any other diagnostics you have already done, are vital in guiding those trying to help you. If `synchronized` reduced your response time, that means that all the concurrent DB *connections* were engaged but waiting, so this pinpoints the trouble pretty much dead on to MySQL implementation.

Answer (score 1):

> Question: Has it got to do with configuring MySQL?

Probably not.

> Or my DBCP connection pool?

Probably not.

> What else can be the reason for the behaviour?

This sounds like the sort of behaviour would would get if the performance of database server was the bottleneck.  Such a bottleneck could be due to the server being CPU-bound or disc IO-bound, or if each query required prolonged exclusive access to the same table or set of rows or something.

Another possibility is that the problem is due to a concurrency bottleneck on the client side.  For instance if each request did something like this:

```
  synchronized (someGlobalLock) {
     // perform queries, updates
  }
```

then you are effectively serializing the execution of the database operations for these requests.  That will result in a linear increase in elapsed time when N requests are performed simultaneously.

---

But to be honest, it is difficult to predict what the cause is without looking in detail at the Java code, the database schema and queries and (maybe) the database configuration.

Comment: As per the `synchronize` thing, that I have profiled well to be able to say that db is the Issue and no external synchonization. The time I have mentioned in question is the time it takes to execute the query not the complete request.

Comment: Though yes all the procedures use the same table.

Comment: @Jatin - I don't think that simple profiling will necessarily tell you if there is a concurrency bottleneck.  Anyway, I've given you some ideas ... and that's probably as much as any Answer will be able to do.